# why does the group by make the sql query so much faster

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

The following two queries give me the same result, but the one that uses group by runs faster.  Does this indicate that optimized queries will favor using group by when possible? Or is it more likely that I'm experiencing some kind of special case?

faster query (less intuitive to me):

```
SELECT     A.Advertiser
FROM         (SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Advertiser, [Final Status]
                       FROM          dbo.Rehenas_View_2
                       GROUP BY [Final Status], Advertiser
                       HAVING      ([Final Status] IS NULL)) AS A INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Advertiser, [Final Status]
                            FROM          dbo.Rehenas_View_2 AS Rehenas_View_2_1
                            GROUP BY [Final Status], Advertiser
                            HAVING      ([Final Status] = N'final')) AS B ON A.Advertiser = B.Advertiser
GROUP BY A.Advertiser
```

slower query (what I was trying to simplify the above to when I noticed the speed difference)

```
SELECT     A.Advertiser
FROM         (SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Advertiser, [Final Status]
                       FROM          dbo.Rehenas_View_2
                       WHERE      ([Final Status] IS NULL)) AS A INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Advertiser, [Final Status]
                            FROM          dbo.Rehenas_View_2 AS Rehenas_View_2_1
                            WHERE      ([Final Status] = N'final')) AS B ON A.Advertiser = B.Advertiser
GROUP BY A.Advertiser
```

Comment: Maybe running EXPLAIN PLAN on both will give you a hint.

Comment: Performance will depend on which db this is.  Certainly appears to be MSSQL but you should state it explicitly with a tag.

Comment: How many times did you try each query?  It could be one was cached.  What indices do you have on the table?  It could be it's doing a hash lookup on the group by.  Do you have a lot of duplicate advertiser/final status pairs?  I think the having filter occurs after the duplicates are removed, whereas I think the WHERE does a full table scan (depending on indices and query plan).

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments you would like Advertisers with both NULL and Final Status's.

This should render the desired result.  DISTINCT often means "I am getting duplicates... not sure why", usually it hides a fan trap.  In this case you may have a cartesian product of 'final' and NULL rows per Advertiser.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Advertiser 
FROM  dbo.Rehenas_View_2 AS A, 
      dbo.Rehenas_View_2 AS B
WHERE A.[Final Status] IS NULL
  AND B.[Final Status] = N'final'
  AND A.Advertiser = B.Advertiser
```

INNER JOIN of 2 aggregates:

```
SELECT Advertiser FROM
(  SELECT Advertiser, COUNT(1) AS StatusCount 
   FROM dbo.Rehenas_View_2 WHERE [Final Status] IS NULL
   GROUP BY Advertiser
   HAVING StatusCount > 0) AS N,
(
   SELECT Advertiser, COUNT(1) AS StatusCount 
   FROM dbo.Rehenas_View_2 WHERE [Final Status] = N'final'
   GROUP BY Advertiser
   HAVING StatusCount > 0) AS F
WHERE N.Advertiser = F.Advertiser
```

Another Idea is to use CASE and count NULL and FINALS with a single GROUP BY/HAVING

```
SELECT Advertiser FROM
(  SELECT Advertiser, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Final Status] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NullCount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Final Status] = N'final' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FinalCount 
   FROM dbo.Rehenas_View_2 WHERE [Final Status] IS NULL
   GROUP BY Advertiser
   HAVING NullCount > 0 AND FinalCount > 0)
```

I don't have an environment to test this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Both queries seem to be a lot more complicated.  Don't they give the same result as this?

```
SELECT Advertiser
FROM          dbo.Rehenas_View_2
WHERE [Final Status] IS NULL

UNION

SELECT Advertiser
FROM    dbo.Rehenas_View_2
WHERE [Final Status] = N'final'
```

Which should also be a lot faster.

Of course whenever you're selecting from a view you can't look at the query itself, you have to look at the view sql as well.  It's pretty much the same as using a subquery, except if it's a materialized view.

Comment: I didn't offer enough details for you to know, but this is a case where every row in the view has either NULL or 'final' in [Final Status] and i'm trying to answer the question, "which Advertisers are only partially finalized" - i.e. some rows meet the first condition and some rows meet the latter.... SQL is not my strong suit and I appreciate you trying to give advice.

Comment: @Gabriel, it would be really helpful to post sample data.  Ideally a small `CREATE TABLE` statement along with a set of `INSERT` statements to create a table with your source data and then a listing of what actual results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you eliminate the outermost group by in both queries, do you see a difference in the number of rows returned? That might explain it.